# How do you go about solving a bug in Blender: language selector in python console

Tags: python, scripting, development

For example, based on: [Purpose of the languages selector in the Python Console](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159716/purpose-of-the-languages-selector-in-the-python-console#)

I am familiar with git and reporting a bug.
But my question is: **How do you go about solving such a bug?**

Blender uses C/C++ and Python. And think its a **python** script bug.
After downloading blender source code and successfully compiled it.

Looking into:

```
blender/release/scripts/bl_operators/console.py
blender/release/scripts/bl_ui/space_console.py
```

and

```
blender/release/scripts/modules/console_python
blender/release/scripts/modules/console_shell
```

Apparently, using the linked example to add `shell` to `space_data` adds the shell environment into console language.
(I used `bpy.ops.console.language(language=shell)` with same result).

However, for the life in me, I could not find a solution to show the language at startup. Unless its hard coded into `space_console`. But that is not an elegant solution..

So, in brief, I think, blender looks up for modules in path, but not picking up console_shell.py? to be added into language list.

Comment: Hi. The title of your question seems to be about solving a specific bug (which I think would be off-topic to this site for being too localised a problem) but the second part of your post seems to be the actual question ("I could not find a solution to show the language at startup"). I would suggest editing your question to focus on that part (however, if it *is* a bug, this would also end up being off-topic). Thanks.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your comments and edits. Much appreciated. However, it's not a bug report, it is more on how to solve such a bug? So someone would show me that Blender uses, for example, bpy.context to look for module files separated by "_". But it was meant to be left out due to bugs.. etc.